# Enterprise Arcitect Keyword updation

Tags: enterprise-architect

How to update Keywords of a element in Enterprise Architect using c#.

as

Element elem;

and elem.Keyword is not displaying.

Comment: -1 because it shows a lack of research. Simply looking at the documentation of [EA.Element](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/element2.html) and searching for **keyword** reveals the answer Thomas gave you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `element.Tag` for the keywords.